# Need to collect objects in an NSArray but

Tags: objective-c

Very Noob question:

I have some event handling methods in a controller instance (created w/Interface Builder); I need to collect objects in an array that the individual event methods need access to.  Should the array var go in the controller.m file?  If that's the place for it, can I write an init method?

Here is an outline:

```
@implementation myController

NSArray *myVar = [NSArray array];   (Compiler doesn't like it)

- buttonClick
{
}

- menuSelection
{
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be able to add objects to your array you will need to make it a NSMutableArray.  Initialization of global variables as you have above, can be done in the + (void) initialize method.

Generally, however, such variables should be avoided.  It would be better to store the array in the controller and initialize it in the controller's init method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't like that because you can't call functions in a C initialiser.

On the assumption that this is a subclass of UIViewController, if you want one array per controller, you should make it an instance variable and initialise it in `-viewDidLoad` or you can probably do it in `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.  The array should be released in `-viewDidUnload` or `-dealloc` respectively.

If your array should be unique and shared between all controllers, the easiest thing to do is create a class method like so:

```
+(NSArray*) myVar
{
    static NSArray* theArray = nil;
    if (theArray == nil)
    {
        theArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];  // Do not use [NSArray array] because you need to own the returned object
                                            // until the program dies
    }
    return theArray;
}
```

NB I've used `NSArray` everywhere as you have, but it's more likely you need `NSMutableArray`.